# How to pronounce the Polish name "Aronszajn"

Tags: pronunciation

Nachman Aronszajn was an American mathematician born in Poland. 
I will make  a talk (in English) on a subject for which I would like to cite some of his works. But since I am not a native English/Polish speaker, I really don't know how to pronounce it.

Comment: /ərən'ʃaɪn/ is what I'd say, since English doesn't have a /ʂ/. In Polish I guess the stress would be on the O, but I don't know for certain.

Comment: Ask the moderator of your section. Or pick one and be confident with it and then ask in discussion afterwards. It'll be good food for discussion that will make the talk memorable.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I would be almost willing to bet that the stress would be on the o in Polish, [aˈɾɔnʂajn]. In English, I would guess at [ˈnɑːkmən əˈɹɔnʃaɪn] (_NAHK-man uh-RON-shine_) if the original stress is maintained, or [ˈnɑːkmən ˈεəɹənʃaɪn] (_NAHK-man AARon-shine_, the first part of the last name rhyming with the name Aaron) if it is reinterpreted. Somehow, an ultimate-stressed version seems unlikely to me (I wonder if perhaps Russian is influencing you to stress it there?).

Comment: @Janus I'm English. I pronounce the first syllable of Aaron as "air". I don't think that will work here. I think I'd say /'ærən'ʃaɪn/ with two syllables almost equally-stressed.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ah, yes… I neglected to consider that _Aaron_ has two common pronunciations in BrE. My IPA was based on AmE where _air_ and the first syllable of _barren_ tend to have (almost) the same vowel. For BrE, I agree that [æ] is a more natural choice.

Comment: Ideally you pronounce it the way he did.  If you cannot determine that you can choose between pronouncing it in the Polish fashion or using English phonetic rules, doing either the best that you can manage.

Comment: @Janus: I believe that *Aaron* is pronounced with the vowel of *air* in BrE, and  the vowel of *at* in New York City. But for *Aronszajn*, /æ/ looks like the best choice.

Comment: @Janus: I think it was actually Armenian rather than Russian. I agree that since the name sounds a lot like a Yiddish compound, Andrew's suggestion is probably closer to the mark.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Նաքման Արոնջաւն? ;-)

Comment: @PeterShor _Aaron_ is varyingly pronounced with the _air_ and the _at_ vowel in BrE. (I notice the OED gives only the _air_ option … I am absolutely, one hundred percent sure that I have heard both versions, though.)

Comment: If you want to find different pronunciations, you can use this site whenever...http://ro.forvo.com/search/Aronszajn/